# Fluid and fixed web page

Tags: html, css, fixed, fluid

Is there any way to create a page, using only valid html and css code, that would allow the page to be fluid (shrink and grow via browser window size), but also not allow any of the data (abbreviated/overflow/etc) to be lost on the page? See the attached image to see what I'm talking about. Thanks in advance.

[css table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NovLd.png)

Comment: Yes, there is..

Comment: Please edit your question to ask something more specific. There are plenty of resources that exist that can help with setting up a page with css and responsive design. You might want to look into `flex-box`

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow". I can make my browser pretty damn narrow and short. In fact, I was able to reduce the height of by browser window to 0 pixels high. "Lost" all of the data due to "overflow".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap, it is pretty simple to learn
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/